# Spawn command with redirection

Tags: node.js

Let say I have this command

```
somecli -s < "/path/to/file.txt"
```

How can I convert the above command to NodeJS spawn command ? I did something like this, but seems like it didn't pass the input.

```
spawn('somecli', ['-s', '<', '"/path/to/file.txt"'], { stdio: 'inherit'}).on('error', function (error) {
     // something
  });
```

I can use the exec command below and it's working, but I prefer if we can see the live output.

```
exec('somecli -s < "/path/to/file.txt"', (e, stdout, stderr) => {
   // something
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To pass file input to command ( STDIN redirection )**

```
$ somecli -s < /path/to/file.txt
```

We can do it something like this

```
spawn('somecli', ['-s'], {stdio: [fs.openSync('/path/to/file.txt', 'r'), process.stdout, process.stderr]});
```

**To pass command output to file ( STDOUT redirection )**

```
$ somecli -s > /path/to/file.txt
```

You may follow Ashish answer

```
let s = spawn('somecli', ['-s])
s.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should help

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("/path/to/file.txt");
const shell = spawn('somecli', ['-s']);

shell.stdout.pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: seems like i got error here
`Cannot read property 'pipe' of null`

Comment: just remove `, { stdio: 'inherit'}`. updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, I did try some other way, and seems like it is working

`spawn('somecli', ['-s'], {stdio: [fs.openSync('/path/to/file.txt', 'r'), process.stdout, process.stderr]});`

Thanks for helping though.